# Beginner Python program flow wrong somewhere

Tags: python

```
import random
bored = input('Are you bored? Please answer with a \'yes\' or \'no\'')
activities = ['Read a book', 'Watch a movie', 'Do some physical activities you enjoy', 'Play a card game', 'Bake something', 'Finish something you never fnished.']

if bored == 'no' or 'No':
    print('Then what are you doing here?')
else:
    if bored == 'yes' or 'Yes':
        print(random.choice(activities))
```

this code don't do what it should.

can please somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import random 

bored = input("Are you bored? Please answer with a 'yes' or 'no': ") 

activities = ['Read a book', 'Watch a movie', 'Do some physical activities you enjoy', 'Play a card game', 'Bake something', 'Finish something you never fnished.']

if bored == 'no' or bored == 'No': 
  print('Then what are you doing here?') 
else: 
  print(random.choice(activities))
```

**Issues**

1. Incorrect conditional

These conditional do not produce what you expect (i.e. always act as True)

```
if bored == 'no' or 'No':

if bored == 'yes' or 'Yes':
```

Use one of these three options:

```
if bored == 'no' or bored == 'No':

if bored.lower() == 'no':

if bored in ('No', 'no'):
```

2. On booleans no need to check both values (i.e. 'no' and 'yes')

Simplify this:

```
if bored == 'no' or 'No':                  # incorrect conditional
  print('Then what are you doing here?') 
else:                                     
    if bored == 'yes' or 'Yes':            # no need to check for 'yes'
        print(random.choice(activities))
```

To:

```
if bored == 'no' or bored == 'No': 
    print('Then what are you doing here?') 
else:
    print(random.choice(activities))
```